# ROS2 Humble Issues Sending and Recieving messages with Wireless Communication

Tags: ros2, ros-humble, wireless

I am running ROS2 Humble on multiple computers across a wireless system but have been having some issues with data rates and node visibility. I haven't had any problems when testing with an Ethernet cable, just the wireless. The setup I'm running has the following specs:
Ubuntu 22.04 running on both computers
ROS2 Humble on both as well
A wireless connection between the two computers
Either over wifi or through a radio setup
Several nodes running on both halves that need to be visible from the other side
One of the computers is being accessed through ssh over the same wireless connection

I have been running into two sets of issues that at first glance seem to be connected but I’m not certain if they are. The first, and most problematic in my case is the abysmal data-rates across the network. Everything works fine if plugged in through Ethernet, but when switching over to the radio or wifi setup it isn’t at a functional level. I am trying to get image data from one computer to another using the image_transport republisher. This simply does not work, if I’m compressing the images on Computer A, Computer B can see the topic but a `ros2 topic echo` results in either nothing being output, or something similar to the following error:

```
A message was lost!!!
    total count change:1
    total count: 9---
```

I have followed the ros2 dds guide [here](https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/How-To-Guides/DDS-tuning.html), decreased the ipfrag_time to 3, increased the ipfrag_high_threshold to 128 MB, and turned off wifi power save to no avail. I also attempted having a republisher that would take the compressed images and send them with the Best Effort QOS between the computers but that did not work either. After that failed, I tried switching the DDS I was using to Cyclone but the results were very similar.

The other issue that I am facing, which may or may not be related, is that after running and killing nodes, both computers lose access to all nodes that aren’t being run locally. After installing and running the nodes with Cyclone, this problem sometimes escalates to the point where running `ros2 node list`, `ros2 topic list`, or any of the `ros2 daemon` commands causes the terminal to hang indefinitely until the computer is turned off and on again.

Comment: Can you check please, by using `$ifconfig that both devices are in the same network and subnet mask?